# In a metric space $(X,d)$, for every Cauchy Sequence in $X$, and $z \in X$, the numeric succession $\{d(x_n;z)\}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Good night,

I'm studying for a test and out teacher gives us a guide for it, but after trying i can't solve the last exercise, so any help would be appreciated.

Prove that, for every Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ and for every $z \in X$, the numeric succession of real numbers $\{d(x_n;z)\}$ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove that $d(x_n,z)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$. What do we know about Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb R$?

Full proof:

> Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $x_n$ is a cauchy sequence there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that if $n,m>N$ we have $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$. Now notice $d(x_m,x_n)+d(x_n,z) \geq d(x_m,z)$ from where $d(x_m,x_n)\geq d(x_n,z)-d(x_m,z)$. Analogously $d(x_n,x_m)+d(x_m,z)\geq d(x_n,z)$ and so $d(x_n,x_m)\geq d(x_n,z)-d(x_m,z)$. From here $\epsilon>d(x_n,x_m)\geq|(x_n,z)-(x_m,z)|$. Proving $\{d(x_n,z)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and every Cauchy Sequence in $\mathbb R$ converges.

Comment: i think i get all of it, i just have a question,how can you get sure that $d(x_n,z)−d(x_m,z)≥|(x_n,z)−(x_m,z)|$? i know that $d(x_n,z)−d(x_m,z)=|x_n-z|-|z_m-z|$, so i get a little confused in that part.

Comment: I think you made some mistakes when writing that last question. $x_n$ and $z$ are not real numbers so you can't talk about $x_n-z$.

Comment: oooh, ok ok actually that was the problem i get confused because i was thinking of them as real numbers, but the real number is the distance between them, now it's all clear, thanks!